# /resources/style.css not picked up in jsp in my spring application

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc

This is my spring mvc project where i am mentioning the config in this java class.

## MVCConfiguration.java

```
 @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.java.spring")
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }



}
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMvcFormExample</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.java.spring</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

## webapp/resources/style.css

```
html,body,div,span,
applet,object,iframe,code,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,
a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,
del,dfn,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,
small,strike,sub,sup,tt,var,
dd,dl,dt,li,ol,ul,
fieldset,form,label,legend,
table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-align: left;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
q:before,q:after,
blockquote:before,blockquote:after {
    content: "";
}

#header{
    background-color:#2B477D;
    width:1600000px;
    float:left;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0 30px 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background: #CBD4E5;
}

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px 0 0 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#navigation {
    height: 36px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0 0px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

## webapp/WEB_INF/views/AddModifyCustomer.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Manage Customer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Please suggest me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/tyles.css">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers are best when they include explanation rather than just code. Care to add some explanation about what why the OP should try this code?

Answer (score -1):

`AddModifyCustomer.jsp` is expecting to find the style sheet at `WEB_INF/views/resources/styles.css`.

Is that where it is?